# How do I call a php file with axios?

Tags: php, vue.js

I am doing a CRUD with vue.js and php. I installed the axios and I believe it is working. I just don't know how to call the php file that connects to the database and creates, read ...

The folder structure:

[image]

An excerpt from my script:

```
<script>
 import axios from 'axios';
 export default {
 name: "HelloWorld",
 data() {
   return{
     showAddModal: false,
     showEditModal: false,
     showDeleteModal: false,
     errorMsg: "",
     successMsg: "",
     projects: [],
     newProject: {
       title: "",
     },
     currentProject: {},
  }
},
created: function () {
  this.getAllProjects();
},
methods: {
  getAllProjects: function () {
    axios
      .get("../php/action.php?action=read")
      .then(function (response) {
        if (response.data.error) {
          this.errorMsg = response.data.message;
        } else {
          this.projects = response.data.projects;
        }
      });
  },
```

Comment: You are going to need some sort of PHP server running to be able to call it. What is your current set up for running the PHP file?

Comment: It is true, have is this detail. How can I solve this? Would xampp work?

Comment: What do you mean by "call"? Why not use an AJAX request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In axios you are referencing a file which will not work

```js
methods: {
  getAllProjects: function () {
    axios
      .get("../php/action.php?action=read") // This will not work
      .then(function (response) {
        if (response.data.error) {
          this.errorMsg = response.data.message;
        } else {
          this.projects = response.data.projects;
        }
      });
  },
```

Axios makes http requests meaning it needs to be calling a server. You will need to have the PHP file running on some sort of server to be able to call it from axios

```js
methods: {
  getAllProjects: function () {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8000/some-url") // This will work
      .then(function (response) {
        if (response.data.error) {
          this.errorMsg = response.data.message;
        } else {
          this.projects = response.data.projects;
        }
      });
  },
```

If working with windows, look into WAMP, if working in OSX look into MAMP

These are two simple PHP servers you can configure

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think this is the best solution as it (for me) works locally and when running in production!

```
this.axios.get(`/thef_file_you_want_to_get/execute.php?, //query-params...
               function (req, res) {
                    // for testing cors...
                    // res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
               }

              ).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
```

By removing the origin, 'http(s)://localhost:3000' for example, the request will happen to the current domain. 'yourwebsite.com' => https://yourwebsite.com **/thef_file_you_want_to_get/execute.php?** for example.